# Url editing on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

Suppose I am having an url like: http://localhost:4647/Project/MyList.aspx.

On postback I want add some parameter(pageNo=4) to the url like: http://localhost:4647/Project/MyList.aspx?pageNo=4

Can I add "pageNo=4" to the url on postback as shown above? If yes please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the client's URL from server-side code *without redirecting*.

Clients don't normally read URLs from server responses. (An HTTP response doesn't even contain the URL, except when redirecting; see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) and [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for details.)

Having said that, [redirecting after posting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) is a very good idea anyway - consider using that technique.

Comment: Yup - as in Reponse.Redirect()

Answer (score 0):

Set the `form` `method` type define to `get` and keep a `hidden` `input` with `4` value and name `pageNo`. Assuming you have done this at: http://localhost:4647/Project/MyList.aspx.

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="get">
  <input name="pageNo" type="hidden" value="4"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In other case, if we assume that we standing on a different page and moving from there to `MyList.aspx` then define `action` attribute of form. We call that page Default.aspx

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="get" action="MyList.aspx">
  <input name="pageNo" type="hidden" value="4"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, we just defined `action` attribute of the `form`.

And [you should know when to use `get` and when to `post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can try: you can use a hidden input and set the value on server side, and read it on the client side.

Server:

```
hdnPageNumber.Value = "4";
```

Client:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hdnPageNumber" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  />




if ($('#hdnPageNumber').val() == "4")
{
....
}
```